# how to add sourceset in gradle java custom plugin

Tags: java, unit-testing, docker, gradle, plugins

using gradle 4.7

I would like to add new sourceset for test integration classes. Seperated from the main test sourceset it will have some other dependencies and would have seperate task to run the tests.

Can it be done using a custom java gradle plugin?

Here is the code and the project using it.

https://github.com/gadieichhorn/gradle-java-multimodule/tree/master/buildSrc

beacuse these tests use the docker image produced from the build it should only run after the build, not like the normal tests would.

any sample or contribution will be appreciated.

```
        project.getPlugins().withType(JavaPlugin.class, javaPlugin -> {

            JavaPluginConvention javaConvention = project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class);

            SourceSet main = javaConvention.getSourceSets().getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME);
            SourceSet test = javaConvention.getSourceSets().getByName(SourceSet.TEST_SOURCE_SET_NAME);

            final Configuration integrationImplementation = project.getConfigurations().create("integrationImplementation")
                    .setExtendsFrom(Arrays.asList(project.getConfigurations().getByName("testImplementation")))
                    .setVisible(false)
                    .setDescription("Integration Implementation");

            project.getDependencies().add(integrationImplementation.getName(), "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.7.1");

            final Configuration integrationRuntimeOnly = project.getConfigurations().create("integrationRuntimeOnly")
                    .setExtendsFrom(Arrays.asList(project.getConfigurations().getByName("testRuntimeOnly")))
                    .setVisible(false)
                    .setDescription("Integration Runtime Only ");

//            project.getDependencies().add(integrationRuntimeOnly.getName(), "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.7.1");

            final SourceSet integration = javaConvention.getSourceSets().create("integration", sourceSet -> {
                sourceSet.getJava().srcDir(Arrays.asList("src/integration/java"));
                sourceSet.getResources().srcDir("src/integration/resources");
                sourceSet.setCompileClasspath(project.files(main.getOutput(), test.getOutput()));
                sourceSet.setRuntimeClasspath(project.files(main.getOutput(), test.getOutput()));
                sourceSet.setRuntimeClasspath(sourceSet.getOutput());
            });

            project.getTasks().create("e2e", Test.class, e2e -> {
                e2e.setTestClassesDirs(integration.getOutput().getClassesDirs());
                e2e.setClasspath(integration.getRuntimeClasspath());
            });

        });
```

Comment: The [Java Plugin User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) has it covered.

Comment: Thanks @Turing85 but I already have a gradle script that can do this, I would like to have this in java plugin code so I don't have to configre this on each project.

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/pedjak/gradle-dockerized-test-plugin)?

Comment: not sure, I just need to set the sourcesets correctly and add some dependencies. the rest of the docker stuff is done in the test class code not in the plugin. make sense?

Comment: In this  case, please re-check the link I posted. There is an explicit example for creating an integration test source set (under "Defining new source sets").

Comment: that is exactly what I do, see above. doesn't work :(

Comment: I used the following post to build my own integrationTest plugin for my custom projects: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/

Answer (score 0):

I had added a new sourceSet with groovy - I hope it can act as reference for the java equivalent you are trying. Consider writing the plugin itself in groovy.

```
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  void apply(final Project project) {   
        // add a source set
        File sourcesDir = project.file("/some/path")    
        project.sourceSets {
          myNewEndToEndTest {
            java.srcDirs += [sourcesDir]
          }
        }

        project.configurations.create('yourNewConfig')
        project.dependencies {
            // Add some dependencies here that your e2e test run needs
            // Example: yourNewConfig "org.junit:junit-core:5.0"
        }              
        // you can also use the project object to create tasks, taskDependencies, configurations etc
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [The JVM Test Suite](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) official Gradle plugin:

```
plugins {
    java
    `jvm-test-suite`
}

testing {
    suites {
        dependencies {
            // add deps for all test source sets
        }

        register("integrationTest", JvmTestSuite::class) {
            dependencies {
                // add for new test source set
            }
        }
    }
}
```